# Ruby Thread.new doing weird thing to class call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a piece of code:

```
config_item_relation = OTRS::Relation.new
config_item_threads = []
config_items.each do |ci|
  config_item_threads << Thread.new do
    config_item_relation << Tracker::ConfigItem.object_preprocessor(ci.first)
  end
end
```

Which is causing this error:

```
LoadError: Expected app/models/tracker/config_item.rb to define Tracker::ConfigItem
```

If I comment out the thread creation as such:

```
config_item_relation = self.superclass::Relation.new
config_item_threads = []
config_items.each do |ci|
  #config_item_threads << Thread.new do
    config_item_relation << Tracker::ConfigItem.object_preprocessor(ci.first)
  #end
end
```

The code runs just fine, except of course it won't do it in separate threads.
The referenced file in the error is indeed defining Tracker::ConfigItem.
`class Tracker::ConfigItem < OTRS::ConfigItem`
It's class I use many many places elsewhere with no issue until I use it with Thread here.
I have the same Thread usage against a different, but extremely similar class (same inheritance) in the same code chunk that works perfectly fine:

```
ticket_threads = []
if tickets
  ticket_relation = self.superclass::Relation.new
  tickets.each do |t|
    ticket_threads << Thread.new do
      ticket_relation << Tracker::Ticket.object_preprocessor(t)
    end
  end
end
```

Am I missing something with these threads?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Tracker::ConfigItem` isn't loaded at this point so multiple threads start to try to load the same file.

Require is very much thread dangerous in current versions of ruby and can give rise to a variety of race conditions. I'd stick a

```
require_dependency 'tracker/config_item'
```

The file above so that you are sure that the requiring happens on the main thread rather than your child threads fighting it out